# Como posicionar los títulos en lo extremos de su contenedor

Tags: android-studio

No logro con este código XML que los dos títulos queden en sus extremos inferior y superior, con este código me queda como en la FIGURA-1

Utilice la propiedad layout_marginBottom="0dp" y layout_marginTop="0dp" pero aun así sigue como en la FIGURA-1

Necesito que un titulo quede encima del otro como en la FIGURA-2 CON CERO DISTANCIA AL BORDE DE SU CONTENEDOR

Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:text="TITULO 1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"/>

        <TextView
            android:gravity="top"
            android:text="TITULO 2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Debe funcionar, da clean a tu proyecto y asegura que este layout se cargue en verdad en  setContentView(R.layout.???); de la Activity

Answer (score 0):

Como lo realizas con este layout usando en los TextViews `android:gravity="bottom"` y `android:gravity="top"` respectivamente, debe hacer el trabajo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:text="TITULO 1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"/>

        <TextView
            android:gravity="top"
            android:text="TITULO 2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

debes obtener:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si quieres eliminar completamente el espacio del texto usa:

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, hay alguna forma de que el TITULO 1, quede mas cerca del borde inferior?

Comment: Si ves un espacio entre la fuente y la orila se puede eliminar con : android:includeFontPadding="false"

Comment: Gracias Elenasys, utilice la propiedad android:includeFontPadding="false", pero no tuvo ningún efecto. Estuve buscando y lo único que encontré que funciona, es colocar en la propiedad layout_marginBottom, valores negativos. ¿Tiene alguna contra indicación o problema hacerlo así, con valores ngativos?  Saludos